# android asks for sdk location, I downloaded the zip file from developer.android but my problem is not yet resolved

Tags: android-studio

Android studio suddenly doesn't work

For reinstalling the Android Studio and to remove its setting before installing i deleted the Android folder located in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android After that my android studio still doesn't work it asks for the location of Sdk

Comment: Please, send the error message or error number or something else that can more help.

Comment: As I see you are a Windows user? How did you install Android Studio? Through a setup wizard, or a .zip file?

Comment: exe file directly from google's website